# Writing to text file. Go to new line after hitting certain length

Tags: c#, text-files

This is my code :

```
   protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      System.IO.StreamWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"~/Puzzle/puzzle.txt"));
      foreach (Control control in Panel1.Controls)
      {
          var textBox = control as TextBox;   
          if (textBox != null)
          {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
             {
                textBox.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
             }
             stringWriter.Write(textBox.Text+",");
           }  // end of if loop              
      }
      stringWriter.Close();        
   }// end of button
```

For example my text file looks like this :

```
,S,U,P,,,,,,,,
```

I want it to be like this in my text file:

```
,S,U,P,
,,,,
,,,,
```

I want it to go next line after hitting the 4th comma.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i want it to go next line after hitting the 4th comma . How do i do it?

You could keep track of the number of commas you have written so far and once the counter reaches 4 simply reset it to 0 and add a new line to the file:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"~/Puzzle/puzzle.txt")))
    {
        int recordsWritten = 0;
        foreach (Control control in Panel1.Controls)
        {
            var textBox = control as TextBox;   
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
                {
                    textBox.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
                }
                stringWriter.Write(textBox.Text + ",");

                recordsWritten++;
                if (recordsWritten == 4)
                {
                    stringWriter.WriteLine();
                    recordsWritten = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```